# Phalcon project index cannot find the controller, and server error is 404 not found

Tags: php, mamp, phalcon

I started this Phalcon project by following the [tutorial](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/tutorial-base#basic), but Im having problem with controller. for example, I set up the exception in Index.php such as

```
$application = new Application($di);

try {
// Handle the request
$response = $application->handle();

$response->send();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

so I am implementing this sign up function as following, in file signup/index.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->tag->form("signup/register"); ?>

<p>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <?php echo $this->tag->textField("name"); ?>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    <?php echo $this->tag->textField("email"); ?>
</p>

<p>
    <?php echo $this->tag->submitButton("Register"); ?>
</p>

</form>
```

and in the root index.php, I have 
    echo $this->tag->linkTo(
        'signup',
        'Sign Up Here!'
    );

but when I click on "Sign Up Here!" from web page
I got the error says
"Not Found
The requested URL /signup was not found on this server."

it is not even showing the exception I set in the beginning, I do know what is the problem why is this happening, I appreciate any help.

then I tried to create a project by using Phalcon Developer tools with command 
phalcon create-project new_project 
I got error Segmentation fault: 11, does anyone know what is this mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What is your address bar showing you after you clicked it?

From my experience, it usually has something to do with your base uri...

If you followed the tutorial strictly, make sure your base URI is set-up like this...

```
$di->set(
'url',
function () {
    $url = new UrlProvider();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
}
```

);

However, if you built your app using the Phalcon Devtools, go to `app/config/config.php` and refactor your base uri section to

```
'baseUri' => '/'
```

For the segmentation issue, make sure that:
1) You are using PHP 7.2 or less. PHP 7.3 support is still in the works...
2) You are using the latest version of Phalcon Devtools.

Comment: Hi, I just checked my code, the setting for URL is exactly same with the examples you showed me, and I clicked "signup" my address bar shows the path as "http://localhost:8888/signup".

Comment: I think my setting up for Phalcon framework is okay, but now I even do know where is this error from or what is the reason.